# Textbooks to study machine learning as a TCS/FM/symbolic AI researcher

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request

I work in the fields of theoretical CS, formal verification, and symbolic AI. Here's my DBLP link to have a picture of my background: [DBLP](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/pid/158/8442.html)

Can you suggest me resources (good graduate-level textbooks) to learn modern machine learning in a principled way sufficient to get up and running to understand current research on the topic?

I'm interested both in a thorough theoretical background as well as some practical skills (probably the two from different resources).

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/164902/755

Comment: Yes, that’s related, thanks!